# how can i make bell notification icon animated in flutter

Tags: flutter, animation

I want to make an animation on a notification bell icon to make it rings like these animations: 
https://icons8.com/animated-icons/bell
or one of these
https://csshint.com/css-notification-bell-icon/

how this can be achieved with flutter?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This animates the flutter alarm icon to shake a couple times you can play some of the variable to get the effect how you want it. This is like the second example you provided  as for the first you would need a custom icon where you could animate just that part of the icon.

```
 AnimationController _animationController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _animationController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500));
    super.initState();
  }

  void _runAnimation() async {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      await _animationController.forward();
      await _animationController.reverse();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            RotationTransition(
                turns: Tween(begin: 0.0, end: -.1)
                    .chain(CurveTween(curve: Curves.elasticIn))
                    .animate(_animationController),
                child: Icon(Icons.alarm)),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Run Animation'),
              onPressed: () => _runAnimation(),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

If you need further explanation on how this works let me know.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this animated_widget flutter package: [animated_widget flutter package](https://pub.dev/packages/animated_widgets#-installing-tab-)

**For Shake:**

```
ShakeAnimatedWidget(
  enabled: this._enabled,
  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1500),
  shakeAngle: Rotation.deg(z: 40),
  curve: Curves.linear,
  child: FlutterLogo(
    style: FlutterLogoStyle.stacked,
  ),
),
```